# About protobuf repeating varint decoding

Tags: protocol-buffers

I use charles and got a protobuf http message from other iOS applications. Now I want to genereate the same http packet but the output is not the same. 
[image: Other App's message]

My protobuf file:

```
message TTCreateConversationBody
{
    repeated uint32 imUid1 = 2;
}
```

I'm using objective-c:

```
    TTCreateConversationBody *body = [TTCreateConversationBody new];

    GPBUInt32Array *arr = [[GPBUInt32Array alloc] initWithCapacity:2];
    [arr addValue:123123];
    [arr addValue:9999999];

    body.imUid1Array = arr;
```

and my output, charles decode it as a length-delimited string:

[image: my output]

it's raw data and mine:

```
8A-26-10-08-01-10-AE-F7-81-80-9F-03-10-D4-E4-82-F0-D2-01
8A-26-10-08-01-12-0C-F9-F6-C3-9D-FA-02-AE-F7-81-80-9F-03
```

What's the correct protobuf file format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're actually both valid... ish.

This comes down to "packed" fields; without "packed", your two integers are encoded as

- [header, varint][value][header, varint][value]
- [10][AE-F7-81-80-9F-03][10][D4-E4-82-F0-D2-01]

where-as with "packed", it becomes

- [header, string][length][value][value]
- [12][0C][F9-F6-C3-9D-FA-02][AE-F7-81-80-9F-03]

note: the actual *values* look very different in the two runs... I'm assuming that is accidental.

[To quote from the specification](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding#packed):

> Protocol buffer parsers must be able to parse repeated fields that were compiled as packed as if they were not packed, and vice versa. This permits adding [packed=true] to existing fields in a forward- and backward-compatible way.

So: serializers *should* write the layout that is defined by whether your data is "packed" or not, but decoders *must* be able to handle it either way. Some libraries, when encountering data that *should* be "packed": determine which layout will *actually* be shorter, and make the final decision based on that. In reality, this can be approximated to "use packed encoding whenever there's at least two items".

Comment: You are right, both two is correct.  I change the format to `repeated uint64 imUid1 = 2;` and the server accept it.